# Colorbox is not loading any content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a problem with my Colorbox not loading any content.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".exampleterms").colorbox({inline:true, href:"http://google.com"});
    });
```

Html:

```
<a class="exampleterms" href="#">.</a>
```

Google.com is just a placeholder url for now, but the idea is the same, I need to load an external URL trough colorbox.

Current result:
Colorbox pops up, and starts it's loading animation but doesn't seem to load any content at all, it just sits there... loading... I've tried this in all mayor browsers and google.com is not down at the moment so what is going wrong?

Comment: Do the browsers tell you anything in errors? Try the error console in firefox, the console in chrome or the bottom left notification area in IE.

Comment: I found some errors in the colorbox script, but I'm not sure if they are important as the colorbox still does show up, it's just not loading any content. I'll put the errors in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MooTools was out of date, now it works again, thanks for the help anyways.

Feel kind of stupid right now.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to load inline content.

What you want is this:

Js:

```
$(function(){
    $(".exampleterms").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="exampleterms" href="http://google.com">.</a>
```

Comment: This is not working for me either, it also seems as if colorbox is ignoring the parameters I send to it, since the width and height is the same as before I put the width and height parameters in the function call.

Comment: Then you need to post exactly what you are doing.  tfbox gave you correct instructions on what to do so if things are not working properly it's because you've left out some necessary information for him to be able to explain your problem.